# How can you exit a Windows Forms application from within an event handler function?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am writing a powershell script to backup and restore databases.  I am using forms to gather user input.  At any point in the information gathering process, the user can hit "cancel".

To keep things tidy, I moved the form logic into separate functions.  Is there a way to "exit" the entire script from within the function?

I tried putting the exit command inside the add_click event, but I get an exception error.

```
  # create Cancel button
  $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(160,320)
  $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
  $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
  $CancelButton.Add_Click(
  {$Looping=$False
   $RestoreFromFileForm.Close()
   exit
  })
  $RestoreFromFileForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: "unhandled exception error" with a thousands lines of unintelligible goop.

Comment: fixed your question title and removed the database tag as this has nothing to do with databases.

Comment: Thanks x0n.  I originally posted in dba.stackexchange, and it was moved here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to close everything when Cancel button is clicked right?

Then instead of `exit`, do:

```
[environment]::exit(0)
```

This will make sure that if the Cancel is pressed, the execution of the powershell script itself is stopped, rather than just trying to stop the form application alone. If there are parts of script that shouldn't be run after the form is cancelled, then go with this approach.

If you are in console and don't want the exit to close the shell, run the script as:

```
powershell .\script.ps1
```

Comment: Wow, that did the trick.  Killed the whole ISE though....bit more than I was bargaining for.

Answer (score 7):

I think you probably want:

`[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit($null)`

as manojlds's solution will kill the entire shell.

Comment: Yeah, but see that form is already being closed. OP seemed to hint that if the cancel button is clicked, anything after that in the powershell script should not be run.

Comment: yeah, but the comment on your answer told me he didn't want that. not your fault - if I could give you half the answer points, I would :)